# Manually inserting Japanese characters into php myadmin database

Tags: phpmyadmin, character

Problem:

I am trying to manually insert Japanese characters into my phpMyAdmin database columns, however I keep getting : Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE5\xA1\x9A\xE7\x94\xB0...' for column 'callText' at row 1
and the japanese character is displayed as ????

Please help me out there, I have set the Server connection collation settings to 
utf8_general_ci

Comment: What is your table structure?

Answer (score 1):

There is a general page explaining all sorts of garbled data problems at http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data.